# MySQL won't start after changing the datadir (14.04, mysql 5.7)

Tags: mount, permissions, mysql

I've mounted a separate hdd to /mnt/temp, and changed *datadir* to point to this. I added the correct settings in apparmor and worked away with mysql for a few hours. After adding `performance_schema` to *my.cnf* and attempting to restart mysql, I am getting the errors:

```
[Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/temp/some_dir/blah.lower-test
...
[ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
...
```

I've since `chmod -R 777 /mnt/temp`, shut down app armor, remounted the partition, manually killed any processes that would be interacting with the partition, and removed `performance_schema` from my configuration.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

From [Learning MySQL: AppArmor and MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/apparmor_and_mysql)

If you want to relocate the data directory in MySQL (in this example, to the `/data/directory`), and AppArmor is not letting you, add the following two lines to the bottom of `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`:

```
/data/ r,
/data/** rwk,
```

...and then reload the AppArmor profiles:

```
sudo service apparmor reload
```

Comment: this worked for me as i have the mysql data in `/mnt/data/mysql`

Comment: after looking for hours and trying so many things, this is the solution that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. My hero!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same, and could figure it was an issue with ownership (this also gave me the illusion of an issue with AppArmor).

May be you can try this (change `/var/lib/mysql` if it’s not matching yours):

```
sudo chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

As an explanatory side note, the user and group IDs for MySQL changed since older Ubuntu release. The previous user ID and group ID was now looking as `hplip` and `pulse-access`. Since the data directory is a mount‑bind for me (on another partition), it still had these previous IDs whose assignation changed.